# Digitally signing a web-http response in Java (using pgp)

Tags: java, digital-signature, pgp, jce

I am trying to digitally sign an http - web response. Essentially, I create the HTML and multipart content-type response, sign the response then append the digital signature to the response.  I think I am close but off a few steps as this is not a true PGP signature since the appended signature is actually HEXtoString. Big thing is to be able to represent the signature correctly so that response can be interpreted correctly. Could use some suggestions here as I am fairly green with this.  Thanks in advance.. below is snippets of code I am using now.

```
    StringBuffer myResponse = new StringBuffer("");
            myResponse.append(getHttpHeader());
            KeyPair pair2 = loadKeyPair();//loads a key pair from generated files

    if (signer==null)
        signer = Signature.getInstance("MD5withRSA");
    signer.initSign(pair2.getPrivate());
    signer.update(message.getBytes());
    byte[] b = signer.sign();
    FileOutputStream sigfos = new FileOutputStream(getFileLocation(0,localTest));
    sigfos.write(b);
    sigfos.close();
    //verify
    signer.initVerify(pair2.getPublic());//pubKey);
    signer.update(message.getBytes());
    if (signer.verify(b)){
        myResponse.append(message);
    }
```

---

```
    StringBuffer signed= new StringBuffer("");
    signed.append(boundary);
    signed.append(CRLF);
    signed.append("content-type: application/pgp-signature");
    signed.append(CRLF);
    signed.append("-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----");
    signed.append(CRLF);
    signed.append("Version: 1");//update this
    signed.append(CRLF);
    signed.append(CRLF);

    signed.append(digSignature);//generated as HexString representation of signed file from above
    signed.append(CRLF);

    signed.append("-----END PGP MESSAGE-----");
    signed.append(CRLF);
    signed.append(boundary+"--");
```

---

```
            myResponse.append (signed);
            ServletOutputStream.println(myResponse);
```

---

The resulting "signature" that is transmitted is a byte-hashing hexToString representation of the signed files. I am using standard java classes, but not sure if other libraries would give me a true PGP representation with characters outside of the 0-9a-f representation. ideas??

Comment: This would be part of a standard.. I argued the same thing, but have no control over this requirement. This forces the web server to do a bunch in the request-response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to a NAESB-EDI standard. Where a file has been submitted in an http request and we are required to produce a particular response.  We are using SSL and the original payload is supposed to be encrypted. The response is plain html (of 4 items) with an additional digital signature of the response. What I have figured to do is to create the response, have existing pgp software create the signature based upon the generated response and then append the signature to the response. Thus I am not using MD5 anymore and I am not exposing keys to public use (except to those that we specifically trade). So James answer is partially correct and without SSL, this offers little if any protection against sniffing since the response is clear text. Yet without the required information in the request, they would not even get a proper response. Likely wouldnt get a response (let alone a proper one).

Answer (score 0):

How is the verification code downloaded to the client?  More details about the application in question?  If it's a verification script downloaded via HTTP then the scheme is fundamentally broken.  You probably need to use SSL, especially if you already argued as such.

Without knowing more about your system, it sounds like an adversary in a man-in-the-middle attack need only to:

1. Replace the public key in the verification code with their own.
2. Resign all "secure" communications with their own signature.
3. Your script sees nothing wrong because the public key it checks was modified by the adversary.

Not to mention all communication is in plain-text (so hopefully no personal/sensitive information being transmitted?)

SSL works around this problem because all the certificates have to be signed by a root certificate authority trusted by / installed with the web browser.  CAs are supposed to only issue certificates for domains to people that control/own them; therefore, the previous attack would not work.

Now, if your client is installed in a *trusted fashion* such that an adversary cannot tamper with it, then you can continue with your scheme and still be secure.  For example, if the client is installed on a client PC by hand, or delivered securely some other way (like via SSL, and/or using code signing).

(I did notice a reference to MD5 hashing.  Do not use MD5 hashes; MD5 has been broken.)

Comment: SSL is used for the transport over http, but the response needs to be digitally signed. So have already verified the user in the request and then sending a clear multipart text/html response with a PGP signature. I understand your comments here and this is supposed to be yet another mechanism for security as part of the standard..shrug.. love standards.. I did realize that I wasnt encoding the signature in base 64(rather than hex).

Comment: Regarding use of MD5, you may want to check out http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/12/forging_ssl_cer.html

Comment: As long as your verification code and public key are securely delivered to the client, then I don't see a problem.  As you already found out, PGP signatures are in base 64 encoding.  I assume you just need it signed so that the author of the content can be verified at a later time in case the user decides to save the content to their hard drive?  (Don't really see a point to this scheme if the content doesn't need to be verified & displayed outside of the SSL web browser).